# Debugging Lightning Components worse in Communities in Winter 19? [NoErrorObjectAvailable] Script error

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-community, developer, summer-18, winter19

Debugging little javascript errors has become a nightmare (again.. feel like this is how it was a year ago and earlier). Simple errors it seems, like referencing a controller method that does not exist, give obfuscated errors now. Take this example, create the component below and add it to a page in a lightning community.

Simple component

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
</aura:component>
```

Now create a handler but leave it as it is by default/make sure it does not have a method called doInit. In a winter 19 org you get the error I mentioned, "This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. [NoErrorObjectAvailable] Script error."

However, the same exact component in a summer 18 org gives you the error you can actually reasonably debug, since it says which component it is and what the problem is:

> "This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Unknown
>   controller action 'doInit' Callback failed:
>   serviceComponent://ui.comm.runtime.components.aura.components.siteforce.controller.PubliclyCacheableComponentLoaderController/ACTION$getPageComponent
>   Failing descriptor: {markup://c:testingErrors}"

This seems to be happening with almost all the javascript errors, like mishandling a return value from an apex controller, etc. When these components are nested and you're working with a bunch.. it is completely untenable to debug if we don't even have the identity of the component (referrals to developer therapists?).

Comment: I would submit this with SFDC directly, in fact open up a case ticket with them.

Comment: Can you provide the code for your javascript controller and helper?

Comment: Have you tried debugging by inspecting the component and applying breakpoints in your JS code ? This has served as the best way to debug Lightning JS code for me.

Comment: add a try-catch block in the JS method (a best practise as well) and you will have more details in the error object which will clearly state which line error originated

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue as well when testing components in salesforce https://speed-power-9666-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/one/one.app

[image: Error in main app]

But when testing the same component in a custom lightning app https://speed-power-9666-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/c/customApp.app I receive a much more useful response

[image: Error in custom app]